# Data send successfully in my API but, my mobile phone signal is interrupted before I get the response code and message

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio

I have an AsyncTask for Posting data in my API. While sending data in my API sometimes network connection is interrupted which is directly proceed to IOexception but my data was send successfully in my API but, my mobile phone signal is interrupted before I got the response code and message. My program rely on response code and success message in order to safely delete it to my database. I try searching solutions online but no topic founds, Any Idea how to solve this kind of problem, Thanks.

Comment: Has the Server received the data you sent?

Comment: yes, tested it multiple times

Answer (score 1):

Data loss is common, which usually causes inconsistency of data state between server and client. You'd better leave the problem to the server in any case.

If the data is not important, you can also remove the data when you receive the right response code, even if it may cause data duplication。

If the data is very important and the server can't remove duplicated data, then it's necessary to add a callback. The callback can be HTTP long polling or long-running connection.